Wrapping a Voltmeter Around a Solenoid
I just read this really interesting paper by Robert H. Romer and it has me curious: what would happen if you wrapped the positive lead of a voltmeter once around a solenoid with a linearly increasing current (i.e. I=αt if a is a constant and I is the current through the solenoid, implying a constant dΦ/dt through the area enclosed by the voltmeter leads) and connected it directly to the negative lead. In my limited laboratory experience, which consists mainly of DC circuits, the voltage would be zero if you ever connected the two leads directly two each other. What would the voltmeter read in this case? Would it simply read α? (Or, perhaps -α, depending on orientation.) It seems so curious that you can connect the two leads to each other and get a nonzero reading.
Here is a picture I drew that may help clarify what I'm thinking of:


The link to the "interesting paper" has timed out. Is it this paper?

Lookup "Lewin ring" on YouTube, and you will find examples of measurements around a solenoid or a toroidal core. Be warned: some YouTubers give wrong explanations, just look at the experiments.

@Farcher that is the right one.

Your geometry is a transformer, with the solenoid forming the primary and the single turn of the voltmeter leads forming the secondary. As in all transformers, a changing current in the primary induces a voltage in the secondary. In a more typical transformer, you would coil the secondary winding to amplify the voltage produced. The fundamental principle at work is that a changing magnetic field is always associated with a circulating electric field. Though magnetic flux cannot escape the solenoid, the circulating electric field produced when the solenoid current changes causes a reading in the voltmeter.
The reading on the voltmeter in your drawing will be $$V=\frac{d\Phi}{dt},$$ where $\Phi$ is the magnetic flux upwards through the ring. Note that while the magnetic field produced by a current follows the right-hand rule (so, in your picture, the upwards $\mathbf{B}$ is created by a counterclockwise solenoid current), the circular electric field associated to a changing magnetic field follows a left-hand rule. That is, the electric field in the voltmeter leads is directed clockwise, so a voltmeter connected in the way you show it will read positive.
Assuming an ideal solenoid (such that the return flux through the secondary is negligible), the magnetic flux $\Phi$ through the space between the voltmeter leads is $\mu_0nA\cdot I,$ where $n$ is the solenoid's turn density, $I$ is the current, and $A$ is the solenoid's cross-sectional area. If we set† $dI/dt=\alpha,$ the voltage read by the voltmeter will be $$V=\mu_0nA\cdot\alpha.$$ The quantity $\mu_0nA$ is called the mutual inductance of the primary and the secondary.
Let's pick some reasonable and small (lab-scale) values for all the quantities. I'll take $n=10\;\mathrm{cm}^{-1},A=\pi(1\;\mathrm{cm})^2,\alpha=1\;\mathrm A\,\mathrm s^{-1}.$ Then you'd only observe $V\approx400\;\mathrm{nV},$ which is probably too small for a typical voltmeter. You could increase the voltage by increasing the current slew rate $\alpha$ (or even switch to AC, which will cause the constant $V$ to become an AC voltage as well) or (as I mentioned before) coil the voltmeter leads several times around the solenoid (the measured voltage would be proportional to the number of turns).
Footnote: † You use $\alpha$ inconsistently. In your question text, you specify $I=\alpha t,$ so $\alpha$ is a current slew rate (dimensions of current per time). In your drawing you say $d\Phi/dt=\alpha,$ which makes $\alpha$ a rate of change of magnetic flux (dimensions of voltage). Your suggestion $V=\alpha$ is dimensionally inconsistent with your first definition of $\alpha$ (which I use in the answer) but is true with the second definition.

Oh, haha my bad! I had meant to use Φ=t, like in the paper. However, I suppose Φ and I are just proportional to each other by the mutual inductance. Thank you for the response.
